# Date Interval, count between - with own date/time format

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the count of visitors, for today and for yesterday individually.

My problem is that I'm using my own date and time format, it's saved in my DB like this: HH:MM DD.MM.YYYY, now to get the visitors for yesterday I tried this:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM lst_visitors WHERE country = '$country' AND DATE(visits) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

and for today:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM lst_visitors WHERE country = '$country' AND DATE(visits) = DATE(NOW())";
```

But that just shows 0 for everything.

I then tried:

```
$today = date("H:i d.m.Y");
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM lst_visitors WHERE country = '$country' AND DATE(visits) = DATE($today())";
```

But that doesn't output anything.

Comment: *Why* are you using your own date/time format? Why are you storing date/time as a string at all, instead of as a datetime or something similar?

Comment: Look at [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for a kludgy fix now, but really, store date / time as, well, `DATETIME`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be storing this as a `datetime` type and you should convert them to such. In the mean time, you can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15:50 27.03.2013', '%H:%i %d.%m.%Y')
```

**Result**

```
| STR_TO_DATE('15:50 27.03.2013', '%H:%I %D.%M.%Y') |
-----------------------------------------------------
|                      March, 27 2013 15:50:00+0000 |
```

Applying your fields:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM lst_visitors WHERE country = '$country' 
          AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(visits, '%H:%i %d.%m.%Y')) = DATE(NOW())";

$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM lst_visitors WHERE country = '$country' 
          AND DATE(STR_TO_DATE(visits, '%H:%i %d.%m.%Y')) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I'll recode to datetime then I guess, in the meantime I shall use your solution. Will accept as soon as I can.